# How to format comments in Android Studio?

Tags: android, formatting, android-studio, comments

I am strating with Android studio  (0.8.6) . I would like to know the KeyMap to format the comments in my project. 
I mean... I know "Ctrl+Alt+L" to format code but it doesn't format the comments as below:

```
   int notificationId = 005;
//Issue the notification
   NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: On the line you want to comment, press `Ctrl + /`  to toggle commenting a line and `Ctrl+Shift+/` to toggle block comments

Comment: I need to format the comments not add ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way Settings / Project Settings / Code Style / Wrapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works! Settings-->Code Style-->Java --> Wrapping and Braces tab and uncheck "comment at first column"

Answer (score 4):

I want to help another user to solve the problem with the image below (thanks to @Isura's support)

File--> Settings-->Code Style-->Java --> Wrapping and Braces tab and **uncheck** "Comment at first column"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
CTRL+A, then Right click > Source > Format
```

Hope this will help.